# Simple Injector: Decorator for multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, simple-injector

I have the following inheritance I want to decorate with Simple Injector (renamed stuff to make it more readable):

```
interface IGetData<T,U> { }
interface ICustomerService : IGetData<Customer, Guid> { }
class CustomerServiceImpl : ICustomerService { }
```

I have one decorator for `IGetData<T,U>` named `GetDataDecorator`, and I have another decorator for `ICustomerService` named `CustomerServicePermissionDecorator`. My goal is to have two (chained) decorators for `CustomerServiceImpl`, one based on the `IGetData<T,U>` interface, and one based on the `ICustomerService` interface. I register both decorators on startup:

```
container.RegisterDecorator<ICustomerService, CustomerServicePermissionDecorator>();
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IGetData<,>), typeof(GetDataDecorator<,>));
```

The first registration works fine, a breakpoint in `CustomerServiceImpl` shows that the methods there are called from the `CustomerServicePermissionDecorator`. However, the `GetDataDecorator` methods are never executed.

I guess it's a misconception on my side - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am a little confused about your question, may I suggest you include enough code to make a copy paste reproduce the problem?
Then also explain a bit better what you mean with "decorate with simple injector"?

Do you want the Instance passed by interface to be decorated on the instance of container? Or what?

Comment: I imagine you are asking for `ICustomerService` from the container? You have only configured the container to decorate `ICustomerService` with `CustomerServicePermissionDecorator` - you haven't configured `ICustomerService` to be decorated by `GetDataDecorator<,>`.

Comment: @qujck I assumed `ICustomerService` would implicitly be decorated as it implements `IGetData<T,U>` - that's not the case, is it?

Comment: @MortenBork The instance is supposed to be decorated (by SimpleInjector) with both decorators for the inherited interfaces. I'll try and create a more verbose sample.

Comment: @PhilReif SimpleInjector will not make such assumptions

Comment: @qujck Thanks for clarification. I think I'll have to restructure that part.

Comment: @Steven Yes, that's the structure I have.

Comment: Next question: Should `CustomerServiceImpl` always be wrapped with a `GetDataDecorator<Customer, Guid>`? Even if consumers depend on `ICustomerService`?

Comment: @Steven Yes, the instance should always be wrapped in both decorators when requesting a `ICustomerService`. The design is such that `IGetData<T,U>` will probably never be consumed directly, but rather be referenced by interfaces derived from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these complex situations, it typically helps to write the object graph by hand, as that makes it much more visual what is going on. It even allows the C# compiler to signal unbridgeable problems.

Based on your specified design, you can construct the following object graph by hand.

```
ICustomerService impl = new CustomerServiceImpl();

ICustomerService dec1 = new CustomerServicePermissionDecorator(impl);

IGetData<Customer, Guid> dec2 = new GetDataDecorator<Customer, Guid>(dec1);

// Consumer depends on ICustomerService 
var consumer = new Consumer(dec2); <-- compile error
```

As you can see in the third line, technically, it would be possible to decorate an `ICustomerService` with a `GetDataDecorator<Customer, Guid>` decorator. However, because `GetDataDecorator<T, U>` does not implement `ICustomerService`, it is impossible to inject that decorator into any consumer that expects an `ICustomerService`. This is why the last line of code in the example gives a compile error.

And as this object graph isn't constructible using plain old C#, Simple Injector will also not be able to do this. It is bound to the limitations given by the Common Language Runtime.

Simple Injector, however, is in this case more restrictive than the CLR as any `ICustomerService` of the previous example can be decorated with an `GetDataDecorator<Customer, Guid>`. A consumer that depends on `GetData<Customer, Guid>` could be constructed. But Simple Injector does not allow this.

One of the reasons to disallow this is to prevent very complex and confusing situations, where decorators are applied in some cases, but omitted in other. That's why Simple Injector forces you to explicitly state the interface on which the decorator should be applied. **Simple Injector will *not* walk the inheritance chain to look for base interfaces,** which seems to be the behavior you were expecting.

Although it is hard to comment on your design, you might want to consider removing the `ICustomerService` alltogether. Especially since you are already using a generic interface. I often see developers trying to hang on to their old interfaces (which `ICustomerService` most likely is) by making a hybrid between the generic and the non-generic, but that hardly ever works out well. You should go full-in and ditch the overly wide, non-generic interfaces. When you do that, Simple Injector will simplify apply decorators for you.

Comment: thanks for your extensive explanation. Eliminating `ICustomerService` might pose other issues, but I'll follow your thoughts and investigate from here